# Add white borders around cell based on specific interior color

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add conditional formatting to a specified range of data that will put white borders around cells with a specific background color. I want this to act like conditional formatting, where it will automatically place the borders when a specific internal color is used (i.e. NOT an one-time executable macro).

[Sample Image of White Borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Du5E.png)

I need to be able to sort **and maintain this border around the colors** (A sort with a conditional format will move the cell color, but not the border). For this reason, I understand this must be accomplished with a macro/vba. If so, could anyone help with a macro/vba formula?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try recording a macro to get you started?

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, recording a macro is a one-time executable action. I want this to passively monitor a range and automatically add borders when a specific background cell color is used.

Comment: Macros can be given triggers which make them run repeatedly whenever certain actions are performed.

Comment: A sort with a conditional formatting will move the cell color *and* the border as long as the 'Applies to` range includes all cells (and it's easier to maintain than VBA)

Answer (score 1):

This macro should do the trick.  Put it in the Worksheet code module.  Just edit the range below to whatever range your coloured cells will be in.  This works pretty well on the SelectionChange event but you may prefer it on Calculate depending on how you're setting colours.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim TargetRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set TargetRange = Range("A1:C5")  'or whatever you want to search

    For Each cell In TargetRange
        If (cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen Or cell.Interior.Color = vbRed) Then
            cell.Borders.Color = vbWhite
            cell.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Else
            cell.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

#### There is an option in conditional formatting to set border outline color:

[Image of Formatting Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isZGe.png)

Try:
 **Conditional Formatting** > **New Rule** > **Format** > **Border**

Sorting will move border color set by conditional formatting.

I think you're looking for that

Comment: The problem with that is I need to link the border controls to a specific interior color, (i.e. if rgb x,x,x then white border, otherwise no border), which to my knowledge you can't anchor a format to a cell background color. This is a live document, so a lot of updates will be made to it, and it is not acceptable if this has to be manually done every time.

Comment: But if you change background color by conditional formatting you can change border also. Otherwise if you change the color manually you can for example create new cell style with borders you want to have.

Comment: Appreciate the followup, Krysztof. I've created a cell style that colors the backgrounds and adds a border, that's way I've built for users to add new data. However, the borders don't move with the sorting. All the cell has is a color and a white border, and in order to conditional format I need to anchor it to a condition, and currently a background color and a white border are not anchor able conditions (at least from my experimentation and what I've read).